# Not able to use correct code for addition in textview

Tags: java, android, textview, sum

I'm a beginner and i'm trying to make a quiz game without database and multiple activities. I want to get the scoring system as a textview in all the activities and it should change according to right or wrong answer. I've been trying to figure it out for over a week now and I only think I wasted that time. Here is the code. The problem is in the addition code...something to do with int and string...i'm not good with the terms so if someone could just type out what the code is and if I need to change anything it would save me from this nightmare.. :)

page5.java

```
    public class Page5 extends AppCompatActivity {

    int score;

TextView scored;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page5);
    scored = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score1);

    Intent mintent = getIntent();
   int score = mintent.getIntExtra("score",0);
    scored.setText(String.valueOf(score));

}
public void rightanswer(View view){

    score = score + Integer.parseInt(scored.getText());
    scored.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Page6.class);
    intent.putExtra("ta_score",score);
    startActivity(intent);
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation(view, 0,
            0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());

}


 }
```

activity_page5

```
      <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#05083e"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Score"
        android:id="@+id/tvLabelScore"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#f6f6f6"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/score1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#e5e5e5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:onClick="rightanswer"
    />



    </RelativeLayout>
```

Page4.java

```
      public class Page4 extends AppCompatActivity {
   int score = 0;
    TextView scored1;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page4);
    scored1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    scored1.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}
public void nocircle(View view){
    score = score + 5;
    scored1.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Page5.class);
    intent.putExtra("score",score);
    startActivity(intent);
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation(view, 0,
            0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
   }
    }
```

activity_page4

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#05083e"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Score"
            android:id="@+id/tvLabelScore"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#f6f6f6"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#e5e5e5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
     <TextView
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView10"
    android:text="NO"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:textSize="70sp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/answeryes"
    android:onClick="nocircle"
    />
```

Comment: It is unclear what your question is. You say the problem is something to do with int and string, do you have an error message? Also, you've included too much code, can you narrow it down to the method or class you think is the problem?

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply...my problem is in Page5.class when I am trying to receive the score from the previous page and want to add it to the score of new page to send to Page6.java....

Comment: basically when page 5 score goes to page 6, the score should be the sum of page 4 and page 5 score...hope its clear.

Comment: theres no error...just not adding the scores

Comment: public void rightanswer(View view){

    score = score + Integer.parseInt(scored.getText()); // this is not adding the values.
    scored.setText(String.valueOf(score));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving the value to a local variable. Change

```
int score = mintent.getIntExtra("score",0);
```

to

```
score = mintent.getIntExtra("score",0);
```

Full Code:

```
public class Page5 extends AppCompatActivity {

int score;

TextView scored;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);;
setContentView(R.layout.activity_page5);
scored = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score1);

Intent mintent = getIntent();
score = mintent.getIntExtra("score",0);
scored.setText(String.valueOf(score));

}
public void rightanswer(View view){

score = score + Integer.parseInt(scored.getText());
scored.setText(String.valueOf(score));
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Page6.class);
intent.putExtra("ta_score",score);
startActivity(intent);
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation(view, 0,
        0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
}
}
```